# Initializing a variable in Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

My code is below:

```
public int workTimeSum(list of parameter){

    int i=0,sum=0,flag=-1;
    boolean b=true;
    Stack<NonOverlapIntervals> str;

    if(st.size()!=1){
        b=recursiveCheck(non_overlap_list,st,Ioj);

        if(b==false){
            st.pop();
        }

        System.out.println("now size is:"+st.size());
    }

    str=(Stack<NonOverlapIntervals>) st.clone();
    System.out.println("Stack is ss");
    while(!str.empty()){
        System.out.println(str.pop().self_id);
    }

    if(b || st.size()==1){
        for(NonOverlapIntervals obj:non_overlap_list){
            i++;

            if(obj.id==ids){

                if(st.size()!=1 && object_Present(st,obj)){

                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    st.push(obj);
                    sum=workTimeSum(non_overlap_list,obj,st,obj.self_id,i);

                    if(sum_max<sum)
                        sum_max=sum;
                }
            }
        }
        flag=1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
```

Above is a recursive code.

What you need to see in the above code is only `sum`, `sum_max` variable.

I am computing the sum and checking if it's greater than `sum_max` each time a sum is computed.

But as I have initialised `sum_max` to zero after each call my `sum_max` becomes 0;

The problem is eliminated if I declare `sum_max` as global variable.
But i am not allowed to use global variable.

I also tried passing `sum_max` a parameter of the recursive function but that won't work.

Comment: WHY AREN'T YOU ALLOWED TO USE GLOBAL VARIABLE?

Comment: Why don't you declare it as a static variable?

Comment: wat difference sould static varaible make sum_max would still be initialized to 0 in each iteration

Comment: Passing `sum_max` as an argument to the function is the correct answer. And it works.

Comment: i tried that but after the function starts returning sum_max loses its current value and gets the value which it had in  the previous call

Comment: @user2713255 Try returning `sum_max` as well. Or store it externally without using a global variable.

Comment: I don't know what language it is, but it is not **C**. Removing the tag

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the variable without needing a second method if you just check to see if it is null if so, initialize it and pass it to the next method (so it will be initialized)

```
//very basic endless example
public void myRecursiveMethod(Object var){

    if (var==null){
      var = new Object();
    }

    myRecusivemethod(var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the way you have phrased the question. You misunderstand: you don't initialise a variable *while* you are recursing. You only initialise it *once*.

To do this, it may sometimes be helpful to create another method for the first step ("base case") of the recursion, which does the initialisation.

However, the code you posted doesn't actually match what you describe to be the case. In the code you posted, you don't initialise sum_max at all. So I'm confused.